# Apply filter to the specific Image Segmentation Matte

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, image-segmentation, ciimage

I need to get Teeth SegmentationMatte from the image, add some filter to it and save it to the new or to the original image.

Here is my current code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        pictureImageView.image = pickedImage
        picture = pickedImage

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let base = CIImage(cgImage: picture.cgImage!)

            let maxcomp = CIFilter.maximumComponent()
            maxcomp.inputImage = base
            let makeup = maxcomp.outputImage

            guard let pictureCgImage = picture.cgImage else { return }

            let matte = CIImage(cgImage: pictureCgImage, options: [.auxiliarySemanticSegmentationTeethMatte : true,
            .auxiliarySemanticSegmentationSkinMatte : false,
            .auxiliarySemanticSegmentationHairMatte : false])

            let blend = CIFilter.blendWithMask()
            blend.backgroundImage = base
            blend.inputImage = makeup
            blend.maskImage = matte

            let result = blend.outputImage
            let context = CIContext()

            guard let filteredImage = result,
                let perceptualColorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB),
                let imageData = context.heifRepresentation(of: filteredImage, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: perceptualColorSpace, options: [.semanticSegmentationTeethMatteImage: filteredImage]) else { return }

            let neededImage = CIImage(data: imageData) // our image with filtered teeth
        }
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As a result, I am expecting to have the original image with filtered teeth. But I'm getting the image with a filter added to the whole picture, not only the teeth matte.

Comment: Did you resolve it ?

Comment: Are you using an image without the depth data?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. matte.pixelbuffer seems to be nil. It probably means the picker is not returning any additional data along with the RGB image.